# Find all permutations with repetitions in given length of elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I would like to write a recursive code that finds all the options to pick, with repetitions, `k` elements out of a list. The code will return a list of lists with all the options.

My code:

```
def repetitions(elements,k):
    if elements==[]:
        return []
    if k==0:
        return [[]]
    else:
        result=[]
        result = repetitions(elements,k-1)
        for e in result:
            e.append(elements[0])
        result.extend(repetitions(elements[1:],k))
    return result
```

My problem is that the code doesn't preserve the order of the original list.

For example:

```
repetitions([1,2],3)
[[1, 1, 1], [2, 1, 1], [2, 2, 1], [2, 2, 2]]
```

instead of:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
```

How can I fix my code?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the proper order, just insert by the beginning not the end: so replace

```
e.append(elements[0])
```

by:

```
e.insert(0,elements[0])
```

Anyway, why reinventing the wheel? just use `itertools.combinations_with_replacement`

```
import itertools

def repetitions(r,n):
    return list(itertools.combinations_with_replacement(r,n))

print(repetitions([1,2],3))
```

result:

```
[(1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 2), (1, 2, 2), (2, 2, 2)]
```

(or `[list(x) for x in itertools.combinations_with_replacement(r,n)]` if you *really* need list of lists instead of list of tuples)

small nitpicks:

- `if elements==[]` => `if elements`
- no need to set `result = []` since it's assigned at the next line

Comment: @Lafexlos: thanks for the info. In the meantime, I was trying to fix OPs code.